# Jsf 2.0 Custom Tag

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I get the following error on every page of my project when I am removing the `MyFaces-2.0` entry from web.xml. My project is created using JSF 2.0.

**Error**:

> One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head'
>   component has been defined within the view.

**web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.JSF_CONFIG_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>MyFaces-2.0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

After removing that entry my custom tag runs. If I put this in web.xml again, then the compiler doesn't go to the component class.

Answer (score 2):

As the message you got says, you have no head component in your view (on your Facelet). Such a component is needed for other components that e.g. want to inject scripts and css resources into the head.

The remedy is to simply add this component on your Facelet, e.g.:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
>
    <!-- The head component that was missing -->
    <h:head/>

    <h:body>
        <!-- Other components here -->
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Head Components are already present in the page.Still there is a same problem

Comment: Head component*s*? You should only have one ;)